# How to search through "post title" and "tags" using WP_Query?

Tags: posts, query, search

In my custom search form, i'm currently using these kind of $args with my WP Query:

```
$args = array(

    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'  => $postsPerPage,
    'offset'          => $postOffset,
    'category'        => 42,
    's'               => $name, //value of my searched term
    'orderby'         => 'date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',

);
```

I would like to search a post by "title" OR by "tag".

I've tried using this code:

```
$query_args = array(

'post_type' => 'post',

'post_status' => 'publish',

'order' => 'ASC',

'orderby' => 'none',

'posts_per_page' => '100',

'offset' => '2',

'page' => '2',

'tax_query' => array(

    '0' => array(

        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',

        'field' => 'name',

        'terms' => array('test'),

        'operator' => 'IN',

    ),

    'relation' => 'OR',

),

'meta_query' => array(

    '0' => array(

        'key' => 'post_title',

        'value' => 'test',

        'compare' => 'LIKE',

    ),

    'relation' => 'OR',

),
```

but the result is empty.

Thanks!

Comment: `WP_Query` does not support searching by title _or_ tag. Firstly, the `'relation' => 'OR'` only applies to the meta queries and taxonomy queries individually. The meta query and taxonomy queries will always be AND. So you can't have meta query OR taxonomy query. Secondly, the post title is not meta, so cannot be queried with a meta query,

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes I know I can't search for "title" but right now my query is looking for title and description of posts, I don't know why but it works. I would like to looking for "tags" of posts, tha'ts why I was trying to use the `relation` function

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the "0" key in your tax_query and meta_query array.

```
$query_args = array(

    'post_type' => 'post',

    'post_status' => 'publish',

    'order' => 'ASC',

    'orderby' => 'none',

    'posts_per_page' => '100',

    'offset' => '2',

    'page' => '2',

    'tax_query' => array(

        array(

            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',

            'field' => 'name',

            'terms' => array('test'),

            'operator' => 'IN',

        ),

        'relation' => 'OR',

    ),

    'meta_query' => array(

        array(

            'key' => 'post_title',

            'value' => 'test',

            'compare' => 'LIKE',

        ),

        'relation' => 'OR',

    ),
```

Also in your first set of args you have `'category' => 42`, but this should be `'cat' => 42`,

Comment: Mh, I will try it. Thanks anyway for your anwser